# Jquery get year and month in separate selectbox

Tags: php, jquery

I have D.O.B select box in a form, I want to populate an exact days base on selected year and month

**Year:**

```
<select name="yy" id="yy" class="box">
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    .
    .
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
</select>
```

**Month:**

```
<select name="mm" id="mm" class="box">
    <option value="01">01</option>
    .
    .
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

I will use PHP function to populate days:

```
function days_in_month($month, $year){
    // calculate number of days in a month
    return $month == 2 ? ($year % 4 ? 28 : ($year % 100 ? 29 : ($year % 400 ? 28 : 29))) : (($month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31);
}
```

In jQuery onchange, how could I get `yy` and `mm` values pass to `days_in_month($month, $year)` like below?

```
$('#mm').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value );
});
```

I don't want the page refresh for every onchange of selected values.

Comment: Youll have to send an ajax call if you don't want to refresh

Comment: You will have to use ajax to do this.

Comment: why not changing your php function to a javascript one ? If you stil need to transfer variable to your php function , you will need ajax

Comment: any sample function in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using javascript , no need to use ajax with php in this case :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function days_in_month(month, year){
    // calculate number of days in a month
    return month == 2 ? (year % 4 ? 28 : (year % 100 ? 29 : (year % 400 ? 28 : 29))) : ((month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#mm').change(function(){

  var mm=$(this).val();//get the month
  var yy=$('#yy').val();//get the day
  $('#dd').val(days_in_month(mm,yy));// i assume that your input for day has id='dd'

 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: @conmen onchange added to my answer

Comment: Do I need to have `dd` selectbox with days options?

Comment: @conmen enjoy coding :)